# Understanding difference between ordered sequences with repetition and unordered sequences with repetition

Tags: combinatorics

$A = \{1,2,3,4,5,6,9,10,12,14,15\}$

I did two questions with this set that asked:
The number of elements in the sequences will be 4.
 1. How many ordered sequences with repetition can be chosen from $A$?
 2. How many unordered sequences with repetition can be chosen from $A$?

So for 1., I thought: there's $11$ choices for each element in the sequence.
So I pick the first element with $11$ possibilities. The second with $11$ possibilities and so on to get an answer of $11^4$.

For 2., I thought: There are $11$ choices to pick from. I can repeat the element chosen. Let $x_i$ be the number of times I choose the $i$th element from $A$ ($A$ is written as it is).
So I solve
$$x_1 + x_2 + x_3 + \ldots + x_{11} = 4$$
for the number of non-negative integer solutions, which is $\binom{14}4$.

However, I'm confused with the wording.
It says "unordered sequences", which I interpret to mean that something like
a sequence $1,2,4,4$ is the same as $2,1,4,4$.
It seems that when i solve it with my interpretation, I consider them as different.
Are my interpretations off?

Comment: No, your interpretation is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your numerical answers are both correct, and your interpretation of "unordered sequence" is correct.
As you say, $(1,2,4,4)$ and $(2,1,4,4)$ **are** the same when viewed as unordered sequences.

> It seems that when i solve it with my interpretation, I consider them as different.

Take comfort: your solution treats them as the same.  When you model the distinct unordered sequences as solutions to $x_1+x_2+\dots+x_{11}=4$, each $x_i$ counts the number of times a particular element occurs.

Using your set $A=\{1,2,3,4,5,6,9,10,12,14,15\}$, let's say $x_1$ counts the $1$s, $x_2$ counts the $2$s, ... $x_{11}$ counts the $15$s.  Then both the unordered sequences $(1,2,4,4)$ and $(2,1,4,4)$ correspond to $x_1=1,x_2=1,x_4=2$ with all the other $x_i$'s being $0$.

Comment: That makes it clearer! Thanks!